# check-box not performing correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

i have a small multiple choice  page where a user can answer questions and all the answers are stored in the database but the code dosent perform correctly for some reason whatever answer i click on it only displays the first option from the 3 available choices. lets say i have 3 answers apple, pear, window if i click on the firs one apple it will store apple in the database but if i click on window or pear it will store apple instead of window or pear can anyone help me out here here is my controller function :

```
function addanswer() {

    $arrData = array();
    $userid = null;
    if ($this->session->userdata("userid")) {
        $userid = $this->session->userdata("userid");
    }
   if ($this->input->post()) {
        //$arrData["answerid"] = $this->input->post("QID");
        $arrData["questionid"] = $this->input->post("qA");
        if ($this->input->post("qA")) {
            $arrData["answerA"] = $this->input->post("qA");
        }
        if($this->input->post("qB")) {
            $arrData["answerB"] = $this->input->post("qB");
        }
        if($this->input->post("qC")) {
            $arrData["answerC"] = $this->input->post("qB");
        }
        $arrData["userid"] = $userid;
    }
    $viewData['survay_data_id'] = $this->survay->addsurvay($arrData); 
    $this->load->view('survay_view', $viewData);
}
```

**model**

```
   <?php

class Survay extends CI_Model {

    function dosurvay($question_id = null) {

        $this->db->select('QID, Question, qA, qB, qC');
        $this->db->from('tblquestions');
        if ($question_id) {
            $this->db->where('QID', $question_id);
        }
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

function addsurvay($arrData) {

    $this->db->insert('tblanswers', $arrData);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
?>
```

**view**

```
     <?php if(isset($survay_data)) : ?>
<form action="http://localhost/Surva/index.php/survaycontroller/addanswer/" name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
   <?php foreach ($survay_data as $survay): ?> 
        <ul>
            <li><h1><?php echo $survay->Question; ?></h1></li> 
            <li><?php echo $survay->qA; ?><input type="checkbox" name="qA" value="<?php echo $survay->qA; ?>"></li>
            <li><?php echo $survay->qB; ?><input type="checkbox" name="qB" value="<?php echo $survay->qB; ?>"></li>
            <li><?php echo $survay->qC; ?><input type="checkbox" name="qC" value="<?php echo $survay->qC; ?>"></li>
            Comments:
            <li><?php echo form_textarea('comment')?></li>
            <li><input type="hidden" name="QID" value="<?php echo $survay->QID; ?>"></li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="btn" value="Answer"></li>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Show your HTML code & model code also..

Comment: i posted them they are up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, you have assigned `$survay->qA` to all three check box values.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="qB" value="<?php echo $survay->qA; ?>">
```

Check it. It may cause the problem.

Comment: tnx it fixed half of the problem now it  answers if all 3 checkboxes are checked A B B not A B C any suggestions ?

Comment: @EdvinasLiutvaitis Have you changed in the third check box also? your third checkbox also holds $survay->qA

Comment: yes i did changed all of them i updated the code in my question what it looks like

Comment: when i pick the A and B answer and not C it returns A and a 0 for B which should be a word

Comment: @EdvinasLiutvaitis: is this the pbm $arrData["answerC"] = $this->input->post("qB");

Comment: @EdvinasLiutvaitis Change what zamil said and check

Comment: @EdvinasLiutvaitis:glad it worked,but be a lil bit more careful with your code, and you can avoid such questions in SO.